# Bash script to remove user

Tags: bash, shell-script, users

I need to create a Bash script to remove a user.
We use RHEL version 4, 5, & 6.
Lets say usernames are Ray4 & Ray6 & the script name is deal.
Specific tasks for this script are:

1. Does the user exist ?
2. If user exists, backup /homedirectory for this user, remove username and place in /root/DeletedUsers
3. If /root/DeletedUsers directory doesn't exist, create it.
4. If any firewall rules exist for this user, email me the results for those rules and on which nodes.
5. If this user exists in sudoers, don't delete, but comment out.

This is what I have so far. I want to make sure this works, before I run it in RHN Satellite. 
After making the suggested changes. Here are the new errors I am getting now.

```
[root@localhost bin]# ./deal
./deal: line 7: [[!: command not found
Usage: userdel [options] LOGIN

Options:
  -f, --force                   force removal of files,
                                even if not owned by user
  -h, --help                    display this help message and exit
  -r, --remove                  remove home directory and mail spool
  -Z, --selinux-user            remove SELinux user from SELinux user mapping

Usage: userdel [options] LOGIN

Options:
  -f, --force                   force removal of files,
                                even if not owned by user
  -h, --help                    display this help message and exit
  -r, --remove                  remove home directory and mail spool
  -Z, --selinux-user            remove SELinux user from SELinux user mapping

Null message body; hope that's ok
./deal: line 22: [: -me: binary operator expected



This is source code:
```

```bash
[root@localhost bin]# cat -n deal

 1  #!/bin/bash
 2  
 3  count=$(egrep -c Ray[46] /etc/passwd)
 4  firewall=$(grep -c "192.168.5.5" /etc/sysconfig/iptables)
 5  doers=$(egrep -c Ray[46] /etc/sudoers)
 6  
 7  if [[! -d /root/DeletedUsers]]
 8  then mkdir /root/DeletedUsers
 9  
10  fi
11  
12  cp -Rf /home/Ray[46] /root/DeletedUsers
13  userdel -rf Ray [4]
14  userdel -rf Ray [6]
15  
16  if [ $firewall -ne 0 ]
17  
18  then mail -s "$firewallrulesexist" emailaddress < /dev/null
19  
20  fi
21  
22  if [ $doers -me 0 ]
23  then sed ^Ray[46] /#/i
24  
25  EOF
26  fi
```

Comment: Change `if [[ $firewall -ne 0 ]]` to `if [ $firewall -ne 0 ]`.  And similarly, change `if [[ $doers -me 0 ]]` to `if [ $doers -ne 0 ]`.

Comment: And where are you creating the `DELETED USERS` directory? If it is under current directory, then no need of `\` and also use `"` to create the directory. Something like, `mkdir "DELETED USERS"`.

Comment: Also, change `-count` to `-d` in `if [[! -count /Deleted_Users]]`

Comment: It is generally a bad idea (and an invitation to hard to find bugs) to have spaces in directory names, especially if you plan to access them by shell commands and/or shell scripts. Any of `DeletedUsers`, `deleted-users` or `deleted_users` would have been a better name.

Comment: I've tried to add line numbers so that people can see which lines the errors are occurring on, but it seems something has gone wrong... Did a line breaks get messed up in the copy & paste to SE? Anyway, I changed the line numbers in the errors to match. Also, you don't have an error for it, so I presume the first line actually is `#!/bin/bash`—that is, the `#` is not missing?

Comment: Creek, can you explain the reason for changing -count to -d ?

Comment: Ramesh, the deleted users directory is being created under the current directory.

Comment: I just notice that your line #5 has three quotation marks; I guess that is the error which ultimately causes the error message you get.

Comment: Celtschk, yes thank you for your feedback. I did delete that extra quotation mark.

Comment: [root@localhost bin]# ./deal
./deal: line 7: [[!: command not found
cp: target `/RemovedUsers' is not a directory
Usage: userdel [options] LOGIN


Null message body; hope that's ok
./deal: line 22: [: -me: binary operator expected

Comment: Instead of `[[! -d /root/DeletedUsers]]` you want `! [ -d /root/DeletedUsers ]`. Or, honestly, if you use `mkdir -p`, that won't error if it already exists, so you can omit the test.

Comment: You don't need a bash script. You need a central point of identity management and/or a configuration management system.

Comment: In line 3 and line 5, you definitely want to protect the regular expression from the shell. Otherwise if you happen to have a file named `Ray4` or `Ray6` (or both) in your current directory, the result will not be what you intended.

Comment: I agree with @dawud - remotely locate `/etc` and `/root` at least - or regularly `rsync` them if necessary. Then when user management needs to occur you can just add a single script into init processes to `mv` user data as necessary but at least user permissions are centrally handled. Speaking of which - why `cp` and not `mv`?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you use `getent` to check for the existence of an user. This script should get you going.

```
##Check if the user exists using getent command
user_exists=$(getent passwd $1)

##If the user doesn't exist, we need not perform the backup. 

if [ -z "$user_exists" ] 
then
        echo "User $1 does not exist"
else
        cd /root
        #Incorporating derobert's suggestion here. 
        mkdir -p "DeletedUsers"
        ##Use tar or rsync to do the backup as cp will be inefficient.
        tar czvf "$1".tar.gz /home/"$1"
        firewall=$(grep -c "192.168.5.5" /etc/sysconfig/iptables)
        doers=$(egrep -c "$1" /etc/sudoers)
        userdel -rf "$1"
        if [ $firewall -ne 0 ]
        then 
            mail -s "$firewallrulesexist" emailaddress < /dev/null
        fi
        if [ $doers -ne 0 ]
        then 
            sed ^"$1" /#/i
        fi
fi
```

You can call the script as `./deal ray[4]` and then if you need to run for another user you can call it using `./deal ray[6]`. I have not tested the script in my system, but this should help you out as in case if you need to delete any other user in future, you need not modify the script but rather call the script with the username as an argument.

**EDIT**

As per derobert's suggestion, you can omit directory testing if you use `-p` flag.

Answer (score 1):

If `Ray[46]` is assuredly unique, pretty much every test in your script is redundant.

```
printf %s\\n 123 456 | sed '/2/s///'

#OUTPUT#
13
456
```

The above will scan its input for any line containing the `/addressed/` string `2`, and,  if found, will change only that line to contain everything but the addressed string. The following simply deletes *only* addressed lines:

```
printf %s\\n 123 456 | sed '/2/d'

#OUTPUT#
456
```

So `grep` then `sed` is not necessary. True, `grep` is faster than `sed`, but in the time it takes to invoke `grep` *and* `[test]` its output *then* invoke `sed`, `sed` would likely already have finished clearing all concerned files of the offending string.

Then again, if you do want to `grep` then `sed` for whatever reason, the following would be much more to the point:

```
remove=string ; for f in $(grep -l "$remove" $file_list) ; do 
    printf %s "$(sed "/$remove/s///" "$f")" >"$f" ; done
```

Or with GNU `sed` :

```
sed -i "/$remove/s///" $(grep -l "$remove" $file_list)
```

And as mentioned above, `mkdir -p` makes a target directory only if necessary, so this should suffice:

```
mkdir -p /root/DeletedUsers ; mv /home/$string "$_"
```

You could even get a log of it all to review exactly what was done on only those  machines something occurred:

```
#ensure $tgt dir exists
mkdir -p ${tgt=/root/DeletedUsers}
#handles Ray4 and Ray6 cases on a single machine
for remove in /home/Ray[46] ; do hostname #print hostname
#nothing happens unless user's $HOME exists
    cd "$remove" 2>/dev/null || { 
        echo "No $remove found here."
        break
    }
#get out of user's $HOME and mv it
    cd - ; mv -v "$remove" "$tgt"
#strip $remove to only username then userdel it
    remove=${remove##*/} 
    userdel -rf $remove
#if $remove in /etc/sudoers comment file's line and and copy change to stderr
    sed -nei "/$remove/{!p;b};s/^/#/p" /etc/sudoers \
        -ne "s/^/sudoers change: /w /dev/stderr" 
#print all iptables lines containing string $remove
    grep "$remove" /etc/sys/config/iptables |
#for each rule found append a noticeable marker line
        sed "a--- "$(hostname)"firewall found"
#finish for statement and pipe all to remote cat to append to log    
done 2>&1 | ssh you@host 'cat >>~/Raydel.log'
```

That above assumes your target user has a `$HOME` in `/home` named for the user's username. If the assumption is correct, it only takes action on any machine on which the target user's username is registered.

To do the same without `grep` you can leave `tee` out as well. Just change the `sed` line to:

```
for f in $file_list ; do 
    sed -ni "/$remove/{h;s///};p;\$!b;x;/$remove/s|.*|$f|w /dev/stderr" "$f"
done
```

That will overwrite `sed's` holdspace with each new line `sed` finds containing the string `"$remove"`. When `sed's` through scanning and gets to the last line it switches to the holdspace, and, if it finds any references to `$remove` it writes the filename to `stderr`.

If you run a script like the one I wrote above from your own machine and you `ssh` out to all of the targets then you don't have to open an `ssh` connection from each of them back to your own machine - you're already there. You could remove the last `|pipe` and everything following it and do this instead:

```
script=$(cat <<\SCRIPT
#body of the script I wrote above less the |pipe and all that followed
SCRIPT
) 
for host in $hosts ; do ssh you@$host "$script" ; done >>~/Raydel.log
```